# How to detect blue color object using opencv

Tags: opencv, colors, blob, detect

i'm using that [guide](http://ipr10.wikidot.com/blob-detection) to detect blobs of a certain color.
On that guide, it check for orange's blob and it use this values:

```
int orange[3] = {200, 250, 10};
```

On the guide it says that this values represents the orange in HSV.

I don't know how they calculate this values but i try to check for blue value converting from rgb to hsv but it doesn't work. What i have to detect is this color:

[image: this color]

Any ideas on how to determinate HSV values to detect colors? thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `blue`, it can be used as HSV values : `[120,255,255]`

I calculated it from `GIMP`, an open-source image processing tool like Photoshop. Similarly you can use any tools to do so.

But remember in OpenCV, **Hue ranges from 0-180, S = 0-255, V = 0-255**

But in GIMP, **it is H = 0-360, S = 0-100, V = 0-100**. So you have to apply scaling according to that.

A lot of interactive sites are available on googling. You can try that.

- To know how they convert these values, check its [wikipedia page.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV)
- Or you can check out the OpenCV docs to see how it works in OpenCV :
  [cvtColor()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=cvtcolor#cvtcolor)

I just pasted the relation for you here:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply, but if you see on the guide i highlight, color check is made in function of color variance and it use value for hue greater than 180...

Comment: please post the link where it says the values in your question is orange.

Comment: OK got it. I don't understand why they given so. But for you to check, just convert a RGB image to HSV and check out the maximum value in H plane.

Comment: If V = 10, then the color is almost near to black.

Comment: do u know rgb values of orange?

Comment: http://www.yafla.com/yaflaColor/ColorRGBHSL.aspx : Check out this link to find HSV values the color of your choice and check if those values correspond to ORANGE.

Comment: yes... i calculate it.. is about 204,61,33.. is used your.coversion and color are pratically the same.. but if i do the same conversion for blue.. it doesnt' work..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13783/discussion-between-abid-rahman-k-and-jackturky)