# Check if an image contains blue pixels

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have this image:

[image]

And I'm trying to write a function in Python that will return `True` if the image contains blue pixels, or `False` otherwise.
That image is just an example. I will have others were the blue colour can be slightly different. But they will always be blue letters over a black background.

So far I have this:

```py
def contains_blue(img):
    # Convert the image to HSV colour space
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    # Define a range for blue color
    hsv_l = np.array([100, 150, 0])
    hsv_h = np.array([140, 255, 255])
    # Find blue pixels in the image
    #
    # cv2.inRange will create a mask (binary array) where the 1 values
    # are blue pixels and 0 values are any other colour out of the blue
    # range defined by hsv_l and hsv_h
    return 1 in cv2.inRange(hsv, hsv_l, hsv_h)
```

The function always returns `False` because no `1` values are found in the array returned by `cv2.inRange`. Maybe the range defined by `hsv_l` and `hsv_h` is not good? I took it from here: [OpenCV & Python -- Can't detect blue objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878254/opencv-python-cant-detect-blue-objects)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not reading the [documentation of inRange](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga48af0ab51e36436c5d04340e036ce981) :D

Which tells the following:

> That is, dst (I) is set to 255 (all 1 -bits) if src (I) is within the
>   specified 1D, 2D, 3D, ... box and 0 otherwise.

and you check for 1

```
# cv2.inRange will create a mask (binary array) where the 1 values
# are blue pixels and 0 values are any other colour out of the blue
# range defined by hsv_l and hsv_h
return 1 in cv2.inRange(hsv, hsv_l, hsv_h)
```

So the solution is to change it to:

```
return 255 in cv2.inRange(hsv, hsv_l, hsv_h)
```

I tested it with your image and returns true, also with a black and white image (BGR though) and returns false.

In my opinion the blue ranges you have chosen are a little far to the violet side... You may use a hsv colorpicker like this one http://colorizer.org/ and select the ranges you will like. Just rememeber OpenCV uses H -> Hue / 2 and  S and V are like percentages (0-100) and you just divide them by 100 (0-1.) and multiply them by 255.

Answer (score 2):

You could have just used [`np.any()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) instead. It will return `True` if any one pixel has a value of 255.

So instead of

`return 1 in cv2.inRange(hsv, hsv_l, hsv_h)`,

you can just add the following:

`return np.any(cv2.inRange(hsv, hsv_l, hsv_h))`

**Update:**

As @AKX mentioned in the comments you could rather try out the following:

`return cv2.inRange(hsv, hsv_l, hsv_h).any()`

Comment: You don't need numpy's `np.any` for this, just regular ol' Python standard library `any()` will do.

Comment: I meant the any global (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) but that works too! :D